# Однородные придаточные и их разборы

Tags: придаточные

> Я знаю, что принц меня освободит, и тогда мы поженимся.

Как я понимаю, "и тогда мы поженимся" не является однородным придаточным, и поэтому мы должны ставить знак.
Важно понять другое: как нужно **разбирать** эту конструкцию:

1)Это будет ССК, где есть только одно придаточное? В этом случае "и тогда мы поженимся" рассматривается как новая основа независимого предложения, которая присоединяется сочинительным союзом? Таким образом, у нас подчинительная и сочинительная связь в предложении?
2)Это будет СПП, где есть два неоднородных придаточных. В этом случае "и тогда мы поженимся" от чего будет зависеть? От "я знаю"? Какой тип подчинения придаточных тогда здесь будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) *Я знаю, что **принц меня освободит**, и **тогда мы поженимся.***

Схема: [глагол  *знаю*], (что  ), и [  ].

Три предиктивные основы, подчинительная и сочинительная связь.

Подчинительная связь: союз ***ЧТО***, придаточное изъяснительное,  опорное слово ***знаю*** (что?).

Сочинительная связь: союз ***И***.

(1) *Я знаю, что **принц меня освободит** и (что) **мы поженимся**.*

Схема: [глагол *знаю*], (что) и ( ).

Три предиктивные основы, подчинительная связь, союз ***ЧТО***,
однородные изъяснительные придаточные.